# nginx redirect to new url if script name is only contain numbers

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-location

How can I redirect if script name is contains only numbers?

http://example.com/125689   -> http://example.com/news/125689

I used this code but I got an 404 error.

```
location ~ /([0-9]+) {
    return 301 http://example.com/news/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a redirection loop because your regular expression is not anchored to the beginning of the line so it also matches the rewritten URI.

You can restrict the scope of the regular expression with the addition of `^` and `$`.

```
location ~ ^(/\d+)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/news$1;
}
```

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) for a useful resource on regular expressions.